# LINQ two Where clauses

Tags: c#, linq

does anybody know how I can chain my where clauses?

I would like to filter the items in my main list by the items found in the second result.

I have the following example code

```
@foreach (var artikel in Controller.Artikel
    .Where(x => x.LieferantenArtikel
                .Where(y => y.Lieferant.LieferantId == bestellung.LieferantId)
)
{
    <option value="@artikel.Artikelnummer">@artikel.Artikelnummer</option>
}
```

The first `.Where` is just to access the list of my object, which has the real check I need.

Comment: Where() needs a boolean, use Any() inside your Where()

Comment: @MarvinKlein Why do you have such filtering logic in your UI?

Comment: @PeterCsala because it works like charme within a blazor server side app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way of chaining `.Where()` into `.Where()` is technically correct. The problem is that the outer `.Where()` under the current situation does not evaluate to boolean. However, that's a requirement. The purpose of a `.Where()` is to define a filter for a collection that results in a subset of that collection. You can check whether `.Any()` item fulfills that condition:

```
@foreach (var artikel in Controller.Artikel
    .Where(x => x.LieferantenArtikel
                .Any(y => y.Lieferant.LieferantId == bestellung.LieferantId))
)
{
    <option value="@artikel.Artikelnummer">@artikel.Artikelnummer</option>
}
```

.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've searched!

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more context to the other answers, which hopefully helps you to understand how to efficiently use LINQ:

What you tried to program using `.Where()` is technically "where exists". Translated into LINQ naively, that would be

```
Controller.Artikel
    .Where(x =>
        x.LieferantenArtikel
            .Where(y => y.Lieferant.LieferantId == bestellung.LieferantId)
            .Count() > 0 // naive "exists", but bad; for reasons see below
    )
```

`.Count() > 0` however is very inefficient, since this would require the execution of `.Count()` to evaluate the statement, which in turn requires to determine the accurate result set.

This is where `.Any()` steps in: it only determines if there is at least one element in the `IEnumerable` by checking them and immediately returning `true` when the first item matches. So only if there is no match, all items of "LieferantenArtikel" have to be enumerated and checked, otherwise a smaller subset will do.

Answer (score 0):

I find non-nested LINQs to be much more readable. Flatten things out with `SelectMany`, and then use `Where`. Note that you need to make sure `Equals()` is implemented in `Artikel` so `Distinct()` does its job properly.

```
var artikels = Controller.Artikel
    .SelectMany(x => x.LieferantenArtikel, (x, l) => (Artikel: x, Lieferant: l))
    .Where(x => x.Lieferant.LieferantId == bestellung.LieferantId)
    .Select(x => x.Artikel)
    .Distinct();

@foreach(var artikel in artikels)
{
    <option value="@artikel.Artikelnummer">@artikel.Artikelnummer</option>
}
```

Comment: While I do share your opinion on nested LINQ in general, I think it's probably not a good idea here. You create the full expanded list, create an object for all pairs, then iterating over all of them again to filter, then over the result to select the articles, then again to create the set, which in turn makes many calls to virtual equality comparison members plus it requires you to implement equality comparison for your article type in the first place. All that overhead just to avoid one nesting level isn't really worth it, in my opinion.

Comment: @LWChris While I take your point, I still disagree. My approach to performance is simple: You will never correctly predict where you will have performance problems. Deal with it as it arises. In the meantime, write concise, readable code. Also, implementing `GetHashcode` and `Equals` on stuff like this is usually a good idea anyway.

Comment: But is `.SelectMany(inflate, map).Where(filter).Select(project).Distinct([compare])` really more consise than `.Where(inflate.Any(filter))`? If you're asking "where exists", why not code that?

Comment: @LWChris That's fair. I agree it may be less concise. It's the nesting I wanted to get rid of primarily, so it's not like we're in full disagreement about solutions here - both are fine in my view, I just tend to prefer non-nested versions.

Comment: Yes, I do agree, especially if the nested part is not one method but another larger LINQ chain, or if the nesting goes deeper than 1 level. Btw, another nice way to reduce perceived complexity without sacrificing performance is to extract the outer lambda into a static function with a nice name, like `topics.Where(HasNewAnswers)` instead of `topics.Where(t => t.Answers.Any(a => a.IsNew))`, or with extensions: `categories.Where(c => c.HasQuestionsBy(user))`.